# How to trigger autocomplete datalist programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete, dom-events

I'm using the following (simplified) code. When the button is clicked, the input field gets focussed, however, the autocomplete list only shows, when I manually click in the input field...

```js
const $input = document.getElementById('input');
const $button = document.getElementById('button');

$button.onclick = function() {
  $input.focus();
  //$input.click(); //doesn't work either
}
```

```html
<input list="list" id="input">
<datalist id="list">
  <option>List item</option>
 </datalist>
<button id="button">show list</button>
```

Comment: Tested on current version of Google Chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my understanding, there is no truly native way to do this. There are hackie ways you can control this functionality (Which are usually horrible for ADA).  But what you'd do is create a custom version of this, where you have full DOM control, and then trigger the open automatically.

There is a new method called `showPicker()` which does what you want, the only issue is that there's limited support for it. Chrome 99+, Safari 16+, & Firefox 101+.

My recommendation would be to use this inside a `try, catch` and then add helpful screen-reader descriptors.

---

*Please note, that `showPicker()` doesn't work here, but it does from a native script.  There's an error of `showPicker() called from cross-origin iframe.` on Stackoverflows code thingy.

1. [Show a browser picker](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/show-picker/)
2. [MDN showPicker()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/showPicker)
3. [showPicker() support](https://caniuse.com/?search=showPicker)

```js
const $input = document.getElementById('input');
const $button = document.getElementById('button');

$button.onclick = function() {
  $input.focus();
  //$input.click(); //doesn't work either
  try {
    $input.showPicker();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

```html
<input list="list" id="input">
<datalist id="list">
  <option>List item</option>
 </datalist>
<button id="button">show list</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The default visualization of the `<datalist>` element works only while you type in the input field. But you can provide your own visualization by changing the CSS style of the `<datalist>` element. In the simplest variant, you simply change its `display` attribute from `none` to `block`:

```js
document.querySelector("datalist").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (event.target.nodeName === "OPTION")
    document.querySelector("input").value = event.target.textContent;
}, true);
```

```css
datalist.preview {
  display: block;
}

input:focus~datalist {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input list="list" id="input">
<button onclick="document.querySelector('datalist').classList.add('preview')">show list</button>
<datalist id="list">
  <option>List item</option>
</datalist>
```

Does that help you?

Comment: This isn't very useful to anyone since you can't select the options that are shown, and when you interact with the actual input the list vanishes.

Comment: You can add more functionality (see my augmented answer) if you want to transfer clicked options into the input.

Comment: Even though this is interesting, it doesn't help because the reason I'm using `datalist` is because I want to be able to use the predefined browser styles and functionality for this overlay menu